# Determine status of submitted jobs in NFS server

Tags: c++, linux, nfs

Can we determine status of jobs which is submitted to NFS server. I need to handle condition in which NFS jobs complete than after follow new step.Do we have any library and system call in c++(unix system) to determine NFS job status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach is : Determine the job status in NFS server and get the status after 1 min or something. When the job complete it will it will remove NFS server and assume job complete and you can proceed further for next operation